# Discord.js role permissions for mention and ban command

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have my ban command all set out and working, it checks message author has appropriate permissions, but what i need to add is a check, to check is user1 (message.member.mentions.first) has Moderator role, and return

otherwise if a moderator tries banning another moderator it causes a critical permission error 'DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions'

I have an error message in place but but through a complicated process that message gets negated now.

any helps massively appreciated

```
    if (!message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Moderator') && !message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Staff')) return message.channel.send('You dont not have the required permissions').then(msg => {
                msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
```

the above code checks if the author has permission. how can i adapt to check if message.mention has permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.member` is same as `message.mentions.members.first()` because they're [GuildMember object](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember). So you need to check it as well

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first()
if(!member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Moderator') && !member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Staff')) {
    return message.channel.send("You don't have any permission for that!").then(msg => {
        msg.delete({timeout: 5000})
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! so the above code will check if message.mentions.members.first() has moderator role? thats what im looking for. Trying to ban a moderator still results in API Permission error instead of the message